# Spiritual significance of Goddess Lakshmi serving the Lotus feet of God Vishnu

Tags: vishnu, bhagavata-purana, lakshmi

Goddess Lakshmi  is the goddess of wealth, fortune and prosperity. Goddess Lakshmi is the “eternal” consort  and shakti (energy) of God Vishnu.
Goddess Lakshmi is also considered as, another aspect of the Supreme Goddess.

The  iconography of Goddess Lakshmi  shows her with four hands, which represent the four goals of human life considered important to the Hindu way of life: dharma, kama, artha, and moksha.

The goddess  typically stands or sits like a yogini on a lotus pedestal and holds lotus in her hand, a symbolism for fortune, self-knowledge and spiritual liberation.

Goddess Lakshmi is also seen serving the Lotus feet of God Vishnu.

What is the **spiritual** significance of  Goddess Lakshmi serving the Lotus feet of God Vishnu?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Goddess Lakshmi (Sanskrit: लक्ष्मी} is the goddess of wealth, fortune and prosperity.

**Goddess Lakshmi is the “eternal” consort and shakti (energy) of God Vishnu.**

**Goddess Lakshmi is also considered as, another aspect of the Supreme Goddess.**

Goddess Lakshmi serving Vishnu's feet should **not** be taken literally.

And **should** only be **perceived** to **understand** the **devotional** aspect of life.

Goddess Lakshmi is always seen worshipping  the Lotus feet of Lord Vishnu.

As mentioned in [Srimad-Bhagavatam (1.11.33)](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/11/33):

> The goddess of fortune, although by nature very restless and moving, could not quit the Supreme’s feet.

Lord Brahma explains the significance of this form of devotion, in [Srimad Bhagavatham 10.14.58](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/14/58)

> For those who have accepted the boat of the lotus feet of the Lord, who is the shelter of the cosmic manifestation and is famous as Murāri, the enemy of the Mura demon, the ocean of the material world is like the water contained in a calf’s hoof-print. Their goal is paraṁ padam, Vaikuṇṭha, the place where there are no material miseries, not the place where there is danger at every step.

Though **Goddess Lakshmi** is the Goddess of wealth and presides over all forms of prosperity, the  goddess  **shows** to the world that **serving** the **Supreme**  is **greater** than all the treasures on earth.

Reference - Srimad Bhagavatham(Bhāgavata Purāṇa).

Reference link:-https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb?gclid=COTrlOjKl9ACFc6HaAodm0UHiA

Answer (score 5):

It is not correct to regard Hari and Lakshmi to be separate entities. That is not a correct view. The iconography of Lakshmi serving Vishnu's feet should not be taken literally.

> **Lord both male and female**
>
> The people in general regard him [Lord Vasudeva] as twofold: of the
>   form of male and of the form of female. **The two should not be
>   considered to be separate entities, O lord of birds. If the lord were
>   separate from the female form, o lord of birds, how could the woman be
>   his reflection? Hence the female is inseparable from the male form.
>   The two forms constitute the very nature of the lord. This should not
>   be taken otherwise.** The neutral form is alien to his nature. It is
>   the effect and not his real nature. It is not present in Hari, O lord
>   of birds. **Know that in the form of Hari there is reflected the form of
>   Lakshmi.**

[Garuda Purana, Moksha Khanda, chapter III]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in Sri Devi Bhagwat, Sri Lakshmi gives Sri Vishnu the energy (power of sustenance) through feet. Its all the play of Mahamaya, Sri Adhyashakti who nurtures all the devas through her energy/love and is also nurturing us.

Answer (score 2):

The very essence of existence is love, and there is no love if there is only one being. Love is something that you exchange with others. So in order to dispense and to receive love, Lord separated from himself his shakti, his eternal closest devotees and the jivas, in a inconceivable for the human way.
They serve him and love him according to their spiritual elevation.
Shakti serves in the best possible way to the Lord, trying to create comfort for him with everything she has.

Answer (score 1):

This signifys one form of Bhakti (devotion) named पादसेवन - To take shelter of God's feet. This is one of the [9 forms of Bhakti](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22531/12304):

श्रवणं कीर्तनं विष्णोः स्मरणं **पादसेवनम्**।

अर्चनं वन्दनं दास्यं सख्यमात्मनिवेदनम् ॥