# Are any of Vishnu and his avataras' great deeds not connected with war?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, war

Some Vishnu avatars I can think of connected with war/destruction:

- Govardhana Giri - as part of fighting with Indra
- Bhagavad Gita - inciting Arjuna to internecine war
- Rescuing the earth - fighting with Hiranyaksha

Are there any avatars that are peaceful in nature i.e., not involving any wars?

Comment: That's primarily because Lord Vishnu is the maintainer among the Trinities.. so it's his duty to fight the chaotic forces..

Comment: Siva alone didn't do ganga aavataran, let's not forget the starting point of ganga is called haridwar. Even Lord shiva gave pashupati astra to Arjuna does that mean he is inciting war?

Comment: Why compare Shiva and Vishnu? Govardhana Giri was done to save the people of that village from the wrath of Indra. Killing demons is for saving the three worlds because the devatas wanted him to fight. So, it is for bringing peace by killing demons and evil forces.

Comment: One avatar I can think of is Vamana avatar .

Comment: vamana carried out an act of war through deceit.  Thats why Bali is worshiped in Kerala to this day.

Comment: I won't say it a war. ^^

Comment: Oh That's something new for me. Because we were taught that in our school.

Comment: wiki: "The section 1.8.1 of the Shatapatha Brahmana (Yajur veda) is the : "earliest extant text to mention Matsya and the flood myth in Hinduism. It makes no mention of Vishnu, instead identifies the fish with Prajapati-Brahma.[1][4][9] "

Comment: @SK prajapati just means the generator, Lord Vishnu is also called prajapati, even in Vishnu stuti. Just like how the name Sri can be used for multiple deities similarly prajapati can be used for multiple deities, shiva is a prajapati too. Sri, hri, prajapati, ishwar, isha are titles can be used for multiple dieties

Comment: @SK prajapati means generator, hri means a modest women, Sri means giver of fortune, isha means Lord, ishwar means personal diety etc.

Comment: @SK these are no arguments, you can check the Vishnu shasranama and shiva shasranama, for a matter of fact Lord Vishnu is foremost among prajapatis as he is the progenitor of brahma/pitamah thus known by the name prapitamah. He is also known as yajna prajapati.

Comment: @SK also Vaman became the gatekeeper of Bali in Patala Loka

Answer (score 6):

There are 3 avataras, I can think of which does not include war,

1. Vamana avatara
2. Vyasa avatara
3. Kurma Avatara

While Vamana avatar was to restore the authority of Indra over the heavens, in Vyasa avatar Lord Vishnu divided Vedas in four parts.

> SB 8.22.31 — The Lord continued: Because of his great tolerance, I have given him a place not obtainable even by the demigods. He will become King of the heavenly planets during the period of the Manu known as Sāvarṇi.
>
> SB 8.22.32 — Until Bali Mahārāja achieves the position of King of heaven, he shall live on the planet Sutala, which was made by Viśvakarmā according to My order. Because it is especially protected by Me, it is free from mental and bodily miseries, fatigue, dizziness, defeat and all other disturbances. Bali Mahārāja, you may now go live there peacefully.
>   SB 8.22.33 — O Bali Mahārāja [Indrasena], now you may go to the planet Sutala, which is desired even by the demigods. Live there peacefully, surrounded by your friends and relatives. All good fortune unto you.

Ref: [vedabase SB 8.22](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/22)

> In every Dwápara (or third) age, Vishńu, in the person of Vyása, in order to promote the good of mankind, divides the Veda, which is properly but one, into many portions: observing the limited perseverance, energy, and application of mortals, he makes the Veda fourfold, to adapt it to their capacities; and the bodily form which he assumes, in order to effect that classification, is known by the name of Veda-vyása. Of the different Vyásas in the present Manwantara, and the branches which they have taught, you shall have an account.

Ref: [Vishnu Purana Book 3, Chapter 3](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp077.htm).

One more avatar was Kurma avatar, in this avatar Lord Vishnu helped Gods and Demons to support the foundation of Mandara Mountain for Samudra Manthan.

> tam utthitaṁ vīkṣya kulācalaṁ punaḥ
>    samudyatā nirmathituṁ surāsurāḥ
>   dadhāra pṛṣṭhena sa lakṣa-yojana-
>    prastāriṇā dvīpa ivāparo mahān
>
> When the demigods and demons saw that Mandara Mountain had been lifted, they were enlivened and encouraged to begin churning again. The mountain rested on the back of the great tortoise, which extended for eight hundred thousand miles like a large island. [[SB 8.7.9]](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/7/9)
>
> surāsurendrair bhuja-vīrya-vepitaṁ
>    paribhramantaṁ girim aṅga pṛṣṭhataḥ
>   bibhrat tad-āvartanam ādi-kacchapo
>    mene ’ṅga-kaṇḍūyanam aprameyaḥ
>
> O King, when the demigods and demons, by the strength of their arms, rotated Mandara Mountain on the back of the extraordinary tortoise, the tortoise accepted the rolling of the mountain as a means of scratching His body, and thus He felt a pleasing sensation. [[SB 8.7.10]](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/7/10)

Reference Bhagavatam [Canto 8 chapter 7](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/8/7/chapter-view)

Comment: this is not an answer.

Comment: I justified it by giving you references :) @SK

Comment: sorry no dice: wiki "The earliest account of Kurma is found in the Shatapatha Brahmana (Yajur veda), where he is a form of Prajapati-Brahma and helps with the samudra manthan (churning of cosmic ocean).[5] In the Epics and the Puranas, the legend expands and evolves into many versions, with Kurma becoming an avatar of Vishnu. He appears in the form of a tortoise or turtle to support the foundation for the cosmos and the cosmic churning stick (Mount Mandara"

Comment: You can add mohini avatar too.

Comment: I believe Vamana helped Indra in many wars..

Answer (score 2):

> Are any of Vishnu and his avataras' great deeds not connected with war?

- Shri Ram Geeta (can be found in Uttara Kanda of Ramcharitmanas)
- [Lord Shri Rama explains Navdha Bhakti to Shabri](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22531/12304)
- [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) 10.88](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/88) : Lord Śiva Saved from Vṛkāsura
- [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) 3.28](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/28) : Kapila's explanation on the system of yoga
- [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) 10.89](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/89) : Kṛṣṇa and Arjuna
  Retrieve a Brāhmaṇa’s Sons
- [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) 10.85](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/85) : Lord Kṛṣṇa and Balrama Retrieves Devakī’s Sons
- [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) 10.81](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/81) : The Lord Blesses Sudāmā Brāhmaṇa
- [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa) 10.33](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/33) : The Rāsa Dance

and this could be an endless list...

> Are there any avatars that are peaceful in nature i.e., not involving any wars?

I couldn't find stories related to a war for these avatars:

- Matsya (the one which happened in the beginning of Seventh Manvantara and saved Vaivasvata Manu.)
- Kumāras
- Nārada
- Kurma
- Dhanvantari
- Mohini
- Krishna Dvaipāyana Vyasa
- Buddha
- Dattatreya

and there may be few more as Lord's incarnations are infinite.

Comment: these are "great deeds"?

Comment: @SK Which one is not?...Saving Shiva is not great deed? or Kapila's explanation on the system of yoga? or Lord Shri Rama explains Navdha Bhakti to Shabri? or Shri Ram Geeta?... indeed every act of God is great....ur Qn is invalid at the very first place...u generally don't ask Qn..u simply want to prove some God inferior or superior to another...

Comment: @sv. Sometimes even great sages get angry...does that mean they r not peaceful?...Kapila is one of the great sages... however deleted that...and made it wiki...feel free to edit...

Comment: @sv. No, they are not. Lord rama killed  a brahmin what do you mean that scriptures are created to promugulate hate for brahmins?

Comment: @sv. Stop finding all these political ideas in Hindu scriptures.

Comment: @AnubhavJha 'what do you mean that scriptures are created to promugulate hate for brahmins' - first off, you need to stopping putting words into people's mouths. I said 'these stories' - not entire scriptures.

Comment: @sv. No story is created to be used as politics, yes, there might be some interpolations here and there but Hindu scriptures are quite neutral, they have all kind of characters. Women curse too for a matter of fact whole Mahabharata happened because of draupadi, is this made to keep whole society under women, and scare them others?

Comment: @SK Definition of "Great" changes with person and it is opinion based. If you don't define them, then your question is opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

You interpretation of the avataras , viewing them as war-mongers ("inciting internecine war" ? really? ) is simple-minded and tunnel-visioned.

The avataras are a mixture of heroism in the battlefield and beatific expression.

An example of a peaceful yet great deed is Hayagriva imparting Sri Vidya and Lalita Sahasranama to Agastya.

Now if want to decline this as an answer because Hayagriva went to battle with a horse-faced rakshasa, then the answer is this:-

Suddha sattva is seen only in Shakti. And her counterpart in the hierarchy is nirguna brahman. As soon as brahman becomes saguna, they exhibit traits that can be seen as guna-based (although such arguments are nullified by the examination of dharma). All avataras are saguna bramha.

Comment: Interesting interpretation from an advaitic perspective. I am interested in perusing the references for the story of Hayagreevar and Agastya as well as the references for the last part. Thanks.

Comment: This is indeed a good answer. @LakshmiNarayanan lord Hayagriva appearing before sage Agastya and teaching him is mentiond in Lalita Mahatmya of Brahmanda Purana. @ moonstar if you want to cite you take references from [hinduscriptures website](http://hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/the-brahmanda-purana/vol-iv/chapter-05). Related portion is present from Chapter 5 onwards.

Comment: Thanks @TriyugiNarayanMani . Please feel free to edit the post.