# Details on Nava vidha Bhakti

Tags: vaishnavism, bhakti

Vaishanivsm has categorized Bhakti into nine groups:

> “Sravanam Keerthanam Vishnoo:
>   Smaranam Pada Sevanam
>   Archanam Vandhanam Dhasyam
>   Sakhyam Athma Nivedhanam”

They are:

1.Sravanam – Listen

2.Keerthanam – Sing

3.Smaranam – Think over / Always Remember

4.Pada Sevanam – Surrender the Lotus Feet

5.Archanam – Worship

6.Vandanam – Pray

7.Daasyam – Execute Orders / Dutiful

8.Sakhyam – Friendly

9.Athma Nivedhanam – Completely Surrender

My question is, Has any Acharya illustrated with slokas for the 9 steps of bhakthi and if slokas are available,  what are they?

Comment: Do you want illustration of Vaishnava acharyas only or by others also? Because Nav-Vidha bhakti is general term in Hinduism.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Preferably Vaishnava Acharyas. If you can provide others also not an issue.

Comment: It's from **SB 7.5.23-24**... the post [How can one increase bhakti?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22531/12304) is related or may be it's possible duplicate of that..

Comment: @YDS Pl read the question fully. I asked for slokas also pertaining to this. To my knowledge all the questions are duplicate because there are no questions to ask. Hinduism  is fully covered. If we ask new questions then it will be  opinion based.  It is like doing multiple rounds in watsapp.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan First of all i gave u scriptural ref where the shoka can be found and thats helpful bcz u can read different commentaries on that...2nd i didn't vote to close ur Q...3rd that answer is also helpful bcz it gives devotees name who did that bhakti from Navadha...i don't know why u r angree on my comment..  which is quite helpful.. :D

Comment: @YDS I am not angry on your comment. I told the fact. Slokas are not there, that is what I have asked.

Comment: What shlpka not there? श्रवणं कीर्तनं विष्णोः स्मरणं पादसेवनम्। अर्चनं वन्दनं दास्यं सख्यमात्मनिवेदनम्॥ is there no...

Comment: @YDS Asking about individual alokas for श्रवणं कीर्तनं विष्णोः स्मरणं पादसेवनम्। अर्चनं वन्दनं दास्यं सख्यमात्मनिवेदनम्॥

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan The [link](https://www.vedabase.com/sb/7/5/23-24) mentioned in related [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22531/12304) covers them in details.. Individual Shlokas are also there for few of them...